# tc command to enqueue TCP packets but randomly drop UDP packets

Tags: linux, networking, network-traffic, trafficshaping

On my CentOS 7.3 system, I would like to configure the ethernet interface so that it immediately enqueues outgoing TCP packets but randomly drops outgoing UDP packets at a configurable rate. The `tc(8)` command appears capable of doing this using a basic filter attached to the root `qdisc`, an `ematch` expression, and a single subclass with a default `pfifo` `leaf qdisc`. After reading much documentation, however, I'm still not certain what root `qdisc` to use.

What is the `tc(8)` command to accomplish this?

Comment: You actually want to randomly drop queued TCP packets (RED). This prevents TCP global synchronization. That does nothing for UDP.

Comment: What I wrote is correct. I want to randomly drop UDP packets while allowing TCP packets to be immediately enqueued.

Comment: That is not something that is normally contemplated for QoS because global TCP synchronization will wreak havoc on your network, and RED was developed to break up TCP global synchronization by randomly dropping queued TCP packets.

Comment: Understood. Can you answer my question?

Comment: See [tylertreat/comcast](https://github.com/tylertreat/comcast) GitHub. Its described as *"Simulating shitty network connections so you can build better systems"*.